# JS: Using 'return' in arrow function syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to return every first character of each string in the `animals` array and storing in a new array called `secretMessage` using *shorthand arrow function* syntax. But, I run into the following error.

**Error**

```
/home/ccuser/workspace/learn-javascript-iterators-E3/main.js:5
secretMessage.map(animal => return animal[0]);
                            ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token return
```

**Js**

```
let animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];

secretMessage.map(animal => return animal[0]);

console.log(secretMessage.join(''));
```

Why does this occur? and how can resolve this error?

Comment: With arrow functions, the error you are seeing is because you CAN do implicit returns, like `((item) => function())`, but if you want to do any more than one operation or include a keyword like return, you need to wrap it in { }, like this: `((item) => { return function() })`

Comment: You can do the same with if statements that only have one expression. `if (!notThere) return 'bad'` but if you do more than one operation or include an unexpected token, you can clear it up by adding { }, `if (!notThere) { const bad = 'bad' }`. So your issue is really just a consideration of when you can or can't exclude the `{ }`. (My if statement is a bit janky because of scoping, but you should get the point. It will error out if you use const there without `{ }`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression in an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) is the value for return.

> In a concise body, only an expression is needed, and an implicit return is attached. In a block body, you must use an explicit `return` statement.

You could just remove the word `return`.

```
var secretMessage = animals.map(animal => animal[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the word `return`.

`secretMessage.map(animal => animal[0]);`

The fat arrow function automatically returns the expression.

You only need the return if the function is wrapped in a block:

```
  secretMessage.map(animal => {
    return animal[0];
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `return` from arrow function

```
secretMessage.map(animal => animal[0]);
```

or include blocks

```
secretMessage.map(animal => { return animal[0] });
```

Another issue with the code at Question is that the result of `.map()` is not set a variable, resulting in `.map()` call that only iterates `secretMessage`, but does not define the result at a new array. The result of `.map()` needs to be defined at a variable identifier. You can also shorten the code by using object destructuring

```js
let animals = ['Hen', 'elephant', 'llama', 'leopard', 'ostrich', 'Whale', 'octopus', 'rabbit', 'lion', 'dog'];

let secretMessage = animals.map(({0:s}) => s);

console.log(secretMessage.join(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the return when you have a one line arrow function without braces.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
secretMessage = numbers.map(function(n){return n[0]})
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem - this will help not just the OP but others with similar issues. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)